# vscode - python task runner

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

with vscode i want my own python task runner.

I created my own task runner in task.json. However it doesn't complete and continues to run.

Code version 0.4

My only aim is to run a python app and show the server connect in the new split window.

```
python app.py
```

this is how I created it but its wrong can snyone push me in the right direction

```
// A task runner for python
// Runs a python program
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    "command": "python",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    // "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    //"args": ["HelloWorld.ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    //"problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The task runner currently waits for the process to finish. As long as the process is running we spin the progress bar in the status bar. We have support for 'long' running tasks and executing more than one task on the backlog.